# Regex expression in q to match specific integer range following string

Tags: kdb

Using q’s `like` function, how can we achieve the following match using a single regex string `regstr`?

```
q) ("foo7"; "foo8"; "foo9"; "foo10"; "foo11"; "foo12"; "foo13") like regstr
>>> 0111110b
```

That is, `like regstr` matches the foo-strings which end in the numbers 8,9,10,11,12.

Using `regstr:"foo[8-12]"` confuses the square brackets (how does it interpret this?) since 12 is not a single digit, while `regstr:"foo[1[0-2]|[1-9]]"` returns a type error, even without the foo-string complication.

Comment: Question has been incorrectly marked as duplicate. KDB has a very simplified form of regex: https://code.kx.com/q/basics/regex/. `|` isn't supported and only these ranges: `[0-9] [a-z] [A-Z]`. This won't include 10 - 12. 
For a kdb answer I think this might need to be 2 likes with or: 
`(l like "foo1[0-2]") or l like "foo[8-9]"
0111110b`

Comment: Doc recommends external C libraries for more complicated regex: https://code.kx.com/q/basics/regex/#regex-libraries

Comment: Thanks Matt, does this mean there is not the functionality to use a single ```regstr```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variation on Cillian’s method: test the prefix and numbers separately.

```
q)range:{x+til 1+y-x}.
q)s:"foo",/:string 82,range 7 13 / include "foo82" in tests
q)match:{min(x~/:;in[;string range y]')@'flip count[x]cut'z}
q)match["foo";8 12;] s
00111110b
```

Note how unary derived functions `x~/:` and `in[;string range y]'` are paired by `@'` to the split strings, then `min` used to AND the result:

```
q)flip 3 cut's
"foo" "foo" "foo" "foo" "foo" "foo" "foo" "foo"
"82"  ,"7"  ,"8"  ,"9"  "10"  "11"  "12"  "13"
q)("foo"~/:;in[;string range 8 12]')@'flip 3 cut's
11111111b
00111110b
```

Compositions rock.

Comment: This is very nice

Answer (score 3):

As the other comments and answers mentioned, this can't be done using a single regex. Another alternative method is to construct the list of strings that you want to compare against:

```
q)str:("foo7";"foo8";"foo9";"foo10";"foo11";"foo12";"foo13")
q)match:{x in y,/:string z[0]+til 1+neg(-/)z}
q)match[str;"foo";8 12]
0111110b
```

If your eventual goal is to filter on the matching entries, you can replace `in` with `inter`:

```
q)match:{x inter y,/:string z[0]+til 1+neg(-/)z}
q)match[str;"foo";8 12]
"foo8"
"foo9"
"foo10"
"foo11"
"foo12"
```

Answer (score 2):

As the comments state, regex in kdb+ is extremely limited. If the number of trailing digits is known like in the example above then the following can be used to check multiple patterns

```
q)str:("foo7"; "foo8"; "foo9"; "foo10"; "foo11"; "foo12"; "foo13"; "foo3x"; "foo123")
q)any str like/:("foo[0-9]";"foo[0-9][0-9]")
111111100b
```

Checking for a range like `8-12` is not currently possible within kdb+ regex. One possible workaround is to write a function to implement this logic. The function `range` checks a list of strings start with a passed string and end with a number within the range specified.

```
range:{
  / checking for strings starting with string y
  s:((c:count y)#'x)like y;
  / convert remainder of string to long, check if within range
  d:("J"$c _'x)within z;
  / find strings satisfying both conditions
  s&d
 }
```

Example use:

```
q)range[str;"foo";8 12]
011111000b
q)str where range[str;"foo";8 12]
"foo8"
"foo9"
"foo10"
"foo11"
"foo12"
```

This could be made more efficient by checking the trailing digits only on the subset of strings starting with `"foo"`.

Comment: Thank you for the examples, they would be useful in the case of checking for the length of the trailing string of digits. I am interested in matching only a specific range of values which includes numbers of different digit lengths. For example, matching for 8..12 but not <8 or >12.

Comment: Updated my answer to better answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

For your example you can pad, fill with a char, and then simple regex works fine:

```
("."^5$("foo7";"foo8";"foo9";"foo10";"foo11";"foo12";"foo13")) like "foo[1|8-9][.|0-2]"
```

Comment: You can forgo the filling with an arbitrary character here - empty char will match just fine. But I think think this method will scale easily - the input may have different length digits.

Comment: This matches strings like `"foo82"` that fall outside the range `8-12`